# How do I retrieve OpenID 2.0 identifier (openid_id) when using Apache Oltu with Google OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect, oltu

How do I retrieve OpenID 2.0 identifier (openid_id) when using Apache Oltu with Google OpenID Connect.

Here is the authorization request I am using:

```
OAuthClientRequest oltu_request = OAuthClientRequest.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.GOOGLE)
                                        .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                                        .setResponseType(OAuth.OAUTH_CODE)
                                        .setParameter("access_type", "offline")
                                        .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
                                        .setRedirectURI("https://app.com/sso_return")
                                        .buildQueryMessage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an additional:

```
.setParameter("openid.realm", "<realm>")
```

and the OpenID 2.0 identifier will be returned in the `openid_id` claim in the ID token. See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect

Comment: Hans, thanks! I added that. How do I now retrieve the OpenID Identifier after Google redirects back to my? Sample code? Thanks! :)

Comment: take a look at this code: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/suresh/oidcdemo/src/main/java/org/apache/oltu/demo/openidconnect/client/OpenIDConnectClient.java

Comment: you'd use something like `tokenResponse.getIdToken().getClaimsSet().getCustomField("openid_id", String.class)`